# Write an equation with words in it

Tags: equations, physics

I am trying to write a chemical equation with some words in it. The equation is given below:
[image]

The code I have written for that is

```
\begin{equation*}
^4_2He + ^9_4Be \longrightarrow ^{12}_6C + Highly \quad Penetrating \quad radiation
\end{equation*}
```

The output it produces is this:
[image]

But I want the part "Highly Penetrating Radiation" to be written in vertical order as in the first picture. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will update with the vertical version

Use `\text{..}` for normal (explanatory) text in equations.

It's better to use `\ce{...}` from `mhchem` to display the isotopes and the arrow, however, in my point of view. I've given some variants:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Original version
\begin{equation*}
^4_2He + ^9_4Be \longrightarrow ^{12}_6C + \text{Highly penetrating radiation}
\end{equation*}

Some usage of \verb!\ce!

\begin{equation*}
\ce{^4_2He} + \ce{^9_4Be} \longrightarrow \ce{^{12}_6C} + \text{Highly penetrating radiation}
\end{equation*}

Replacing the \verb!\longrightarrow!

\begin{equation*}
\ce{^4_2He + ^9_4Be -> ^{12}_6C} + \text{Highly penetrating radiation}
\end{equation*}

No equation environment at all ('inline')


\ce{^4_2He + ^9_4Be -> ^{12}_6C + Highly penetrating radiation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Vertical version with `\Centerstack` from `stackengine`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Original version
\begin{equation*}
^4_2He + ^9_4Be \longrightarrow ^{12}_6C + \Centerstack{Highly penetrating radiation}
\end{equation*}

Some usage of \verb!\ce!

\begin{equation*}
\ce{^4_2He} + \ce{^9_4Be} \longrightarrow \ce{^{12}_6C} + \Centerstack{Highly penetrating radiation}
\end{equation*}

Replacing the \verb!\longrightarrow!

\begin{equation*}
\ce{^4_2He + ^9_4Be -> ^{12}_6C} + \Centerstack{Highly penetrating radiation}
\end{equation*}

No equation environment at all ('inline')


\ce{^4_2He + ^9_4Be -> ^{12}_6C +} \Centerstack{Highly penetrating radiation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you think left aligning the text would look nicer? A simple `\eqparbox` would do the trick.

Comment: @Bernard: It would, but look at the OP -- it's centered there ...

Comment: It's only a matter of personal taste, anyway.

Comment: @Bernard: True -- I wouldn't use it this way

Comment: `\ce{A + {a b c}}` is almost equivalent to `\ce{A} + \text{a b c}`